# Unselect radio button on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to unselect a radio button with a click with jquery.

**Wanted behavior :**

1. **If clicked radio button is already checked, uncheck**
2. **If clicked radio button is not checked, check**

Here's my fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2te28/15/

and my code :

```
$('.table').on('click mousedown', '.radio', function() {
    if($(this).attr('id') == $(this).parents('tr').find('.radio:checked').attr('id'))
        $(this).removeAttr('checked');
});
```

My problem is it always gets uncheck whatever I click.

**EDIT : Corrected id transcription error**

**EDIT2 : Both radio buttons cannot be selected at the same time!**

Comment: your markup it's incorrect you have two elements with the same ID and name

Comment: you're using same `id` for multiple `radio`s. not allowed

Comment: Is using a radio button a requirement? In my experience if you want to unselect an option checkboxes are easier to deal with. Write javascript to unselect all when a selection is made.

Comment: @Shaded Checkboxes allow user to select "none, one or multiple" options where radios allow user to select "none or one" option.

Comment: Yes, using a radio button is a requirement

Comment: @PeterPajchl Yeah I know, but if you hook an onselect to your checkboxes you can get 1 or none functionality easier than with a radio button, which is typically a must have 1 option.

Comment: I know the functionnality with checkboxes is simpler, but my goal here is to keep the radio buttons.

Comment: @Shaded there is semantic reason why we have radios and checkboxes, say for selection of gender (and think of progressive enhancement, where js isn't available) how do you provide the correct functionality with checkboxes?

Comment: @PeterPajchl, simple you just make sure all other checkboxes are unselected when one is selected. This way the user can choose to unselect their choice if they misclicked. With radio buttons this is not a built in functionality. I don't want to argue semantics, I just offered that check boxes would be easier to work with in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your HTML. You have change the `id`, but you've to also change then `name`.

```js
$('.table').on('click', '.radio', function() {
  if (this.getAttribute('checked')) { // check the presence of checked attr
    $(this).removeAttr('checked'); // if present remove that
  } else {
    $(this).attr('checked', true); // if not then make checked
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" checked="checked" class="radio" />
      <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="2" checked="checked" class="radio" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2te28/64/)**

#### According to a comment

```js
$('.table').on('click', '.radio', function() {
  if (this.getAttribute('checked')) {
    $(this).removeAttr('checked');
    $(this).siblings('.radio').attr('checked', false);
  } else {
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
    $(this).siblings('.radio').removeAttr('checked');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1" checked="checked" class="radio" />
      <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="2" checked="checked" class="radio" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2te28/67/)**

Comment: Both radio buttons cannot be selected at the same time!

Comment: In the interest of progressive enhancement, you might provide a 'n/a' option and use javascript to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/535dR/1/

**Code:**

```
$('.table input[type="radio"]').on('mouseup', function() {
    var radio = $(this);
    if(radio.prop('nc') == 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // *to work: this needs to run only after the event completes*
            if(radio.is(':checked')) radio.removeAttr('checked');
            radio.prop('nc', 1);
        }, 10); 
    }
    else radio.prop('nc', 0);
});
```

**Updated Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/535dR/3/

With both points mentioned in the comments resolved.

Comment: One little quirk with this is on the initial load if you click the selected radio it doesn't deselect, and will require an additional click. Other than that it looks good!

Comment: Yeah looks great except if you change from one radio to another it unselects the first instead on selecting second and vice-versa.

Comment: No, what i meant is not that both should be selected at the same time, but that the behavior was not perfect

Comment: Is it not perfect in my last demo?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2te28/61/

The `<id>` and `<name>` for the html tags representing the radio buttons have to be unique, so those where changed to:

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1"  class="radio"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="2"  class="radio"/>
```

Then, you can add some simple JQuery Code:

```
var radioChecked = $('.table .radio').is(':checked');

$('.table .radio').click(function() {
    radioChecked = !radioChecked;
    $(this).attr('checked', radioChecked);
});​
```

Comment: Both radio buttons cannot be selected at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" id="radio1" name="1"  class="radio"/>
<input type="radio" id="radio2" name="2"  class="radio"/>
```

then you need to just add

```
$('.radio').click(function(){

value = $(this).val();

if(val == 1){

$('#radio1').removeAttr('checked');

}

else{

$('#radio2').removeAttr('checked');

}

});
```

this works for me

Answer (score 0):

What I do is very simple.

I set `RadioButton.style.textDecoration = "none"` at the beginning.
This doesn't have any effect on the `RadioButton` element, but the setting sticks.

Then, on the `OnClick` event, I check for `textDecoration`.
If it's `"none"` I set `RadioButton.checked = true` and `textDecoration = "underline"`

If it's `"underline"` I set `RadioButton.checked = false` and `textDecoration = "none"`